Does Telekinetic Maneuver work with Titan Wrestler?
The spell Telekinetic Maneuver allows the caster to attempt to Disarm, Shove, Reposition, or Trip a target at a 60 foot range, using a spell attack roll instead of an Athletics check.
It does not inherently specify any size restrictions (it simply works against “one target”) but, a reasonable assumption (and the one most tables I play at have followed), is that this maneuver inherits the normal size restrictions of the subordinate actions it allows.
The feat Titan Wrestler allows a character to perform the above maneuvers against a creature up to two sizes larger than them.
If my Wizard is trained in Athletics, and takes Titan Wrestler, can they use TK Maneuver to Trip a Giant?

The Requirements May Not Apply

It does not inherently specify any size restrictions (it simply works against “one target”) but, a reasonable assumption (and the one most tables I play at have followed), is that this maneuver inherits the normal size restrictions of the subordinate actions it allows.

While applying the the standard size requirements for Athletics skill actions might be reasonable, those aren't the only requirements in those actions. Should telekinetic maneuver also require that the caster has a hand free to Disarm, Reposition, Shove, or Trip, or that they have the target grabbed/restrained for the Reposition, despite targeting allowing for a 60 foot range?
From the rules on subordinate actions:

...The action that allows you to use a subordinate action doesn't require you to spend more actions or reactions to do so; that cost is already factored in.
Using an activity is not the same as using any of its subordinate actions. For example, the quickened condition you get from the haste spell lets you spend an extra action each turn to Stride or Strike, but you couldn't use the extra action for an activity that includes a Stride or Strike. As another example, if you used an action that specified, “If the next action you use is a Strike,” an activity that includes a Strike wouldn't count, because the next thing you are doing is starting an activity, not using the Strike basic action

Telekinetic maneuver doesn't mention these requirements in its description, and casting it isn't the same as using the subordinate action. As such, none of the subordinate requirements apply to prevent usage of telekinetic maneuver to achieve the effects of an Athletics skill action, and therefore Titan Wrestler wouldn't change anything for the spell.

It does not work, but you do not need it
The requirements are taken care of by the spell. You do not need a hand free, and your size compared to the target does not matter.
Why would you need a free hand? If this requirement is ignored, why is not the other?
You pay for this flexibilty by spending a spell slot.

It doesn't as it does not use the skill
Titan Wrestler says:

You can attempt to Disarm, Grapple, Reposition, Shove, or Trip creatures up to two sizes larger than you, or up to three sizes larger than you if you’re legendary in Athletics.

It is a skill feat, and the skill trait says

A general feat with the skill trait improves your skills and their actions or gives you new actions for a skill.

Based on this, you would need to use the skill to improve "its action", that is, not just any Trip is improved, but the Athletics skill's trip action is improved. This also makes more sense considering your feat works better if you are Legendary in Athletics.
It wouldn‘t make a lot of sense that your telekinetic maneuver, that is not using your Athletics skill at all, improves when your Athletics skill improves.

It wouldn‘t make a lot of sense that your telekinetic maneuver, that is not using your Athletics skill at all, has the same limitation as the skill.

I can add that just because a skill feat requires a skill, doesn't mean that its use is limited to that skill ro even uses that skill at all. An example I can think of off the top of my head is from Starfidner and is called "face in the crowd". It is a deception skill feat, that allows you to make stealth checks in a crowd. You can take this and never have to make a deception check to use it. I am sure there are others like that, so just because a skill feat requires a skill, doesn't mean the ability it gransts requires it.
